# Django Rest Framework : Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Images in the current database have one piece of data.

But, I am currently experiencing the following error

`"GET /images/all/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58"
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."`

My Git Hub URL : https://github.com/Nomadcoders-Study/Nomadgram

Which part of the setup went wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw your Github project settings.py file.

This error is because you are using IsAuthenticated backend for all of your requests to Rest APIs. Also you setup jwt authorization system:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
),
}
```

So basically, if you want to create a request to any of your API endpoints, you should provide jwt token authorization header in it. like this for:

```
curl "<your api endpoint>" -H "Authorization: jwt <token_received>"
```

Also remember to setup and API to receive token from it, by providing username and password in serializer.

Comment: Regarding the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`, There may be some variety like `rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication` and `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication`. For me, this answer worked, hence, using `rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication`. Also putting `Bearer` on the authentication will not work. It must be `jwt`.

Answer (score 3):

try this in your settings file

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',),


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your project Settings rest_framework configuration

> settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'('rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication', ),
}
```